# VNC client on Raspberry Pi

Tags: remote, vnc, windows, desktop

Is there a VNC-client (not server!) to view a remote windows desktop on Raspberry Pi, i.e. the Pi attached to my TV?
So that I can see my windows desktop PC there?

I found lots of solutions, where the VNC-Server is hosted on a Pi and accessed from other platforms but not this way round. Could you tell me which application to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called VNC Viewer, and you'll find it in the "Recommended Software" app (under Preferences in the Raspbian desktop menu).

Or, if you prefer the command line, you can do "sudo apt install realvnc-vnc-viewer".

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That works for me :)